# Form-based Authentication using HttpClient - j_security_check

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, form-authentication, j-security-check

I'm trying to authenticate myself to a website that uses form-based authentication (e.g., facebook.com) using the Apache HttpClient Java library.
Using this website's program as a main example: http://www.elitejavacoder.com/2013/10/http-client-form-based-authentication.html, I was able to do it - but there are a few things that I'm not understanding about this program. Here is the code:

```
package com.elitejavacoder.http.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HttpClientFormAuthentication {
    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        String host = "yourhostname.com";
        int port = 8080;
        String protocol = "http";

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(host, port, protocol);
            client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST, httpHost);

            HttpGet securedResource = new HttpGet("/secured/index.jsp");            
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(securedResource);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);

            System.out.println("Http status code for Unauthenticated Request: " + statusCode);// Statue code should be 200
            System.out.println("Response for Unauthenticated Request: \n" + strResponse); // Should be login page
            System.out.println("================================================================\n");

            HttpPost authpost = new HttpPost("/j_security_check");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "yourusername"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "yourpassword"));
            authpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            httpResponse = client.execute(authpost);
            responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);

            System.out.println("Http status code for Authenticattion Request: " + statusCode);// Status code should be 302
            System.out.println("Response for Authenticattion Request: \n" + strResponse); // Should be blank string
            System.out.println("================================================================\n");

            httpResponse = client.execute(securedResource);
            responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);

            System.out.println("Http status code for Authenticated Request: " + statusCode);// Status code should be 200
            System.out.println("Response for Authenticated Request: \n" + strResponse);// Should be actual page
            System.out.println("================================================================\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following questions (the line numbers I'm going to refer to are in the context of the link that I provided above, since StackOverflow doesn't allow to include line numbers):

- What exactly is "/j_security_check" (line 41)? And how did the author knew that he had to use "j_security_check" instead of the name of the secured resource?
- How come that the string "strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);" (line 49), which is two lines after "httpResponse = client.execute(authpost);" (line 47), is different from the string "strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);" (line 59), which is two lines after "httpResponse = client.execute(securedResource);" (line 57)?
  Basically, what changes happen to "client" between lines 47 and 57?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/j_security_check` is a form action so that the container knows that this request is for authentication and the container handles that. `/j_security_check` is a web page address for submitting authentication forms that is specific to Enterprise Java application servers.

`j_username` and `j_password` are names of the request parameters to submit both the username and password. These three should be named in such a way (i.e. `j_security_check`, `j_username` and `j_password`) so that the container handles this request as an authentication request and it can retrieve the required information (i.e. username and password) from the submitted request.

The author knew that he/she needed to used `/j_security_check` because he/she is assuming that he is authenticating against a J2EE app server.  This is not a great assumption.  Notice that the port is set to 8080?  That is the port typically used by Java servers like Tomcat so they don't collide with port 80 on an HTTP server.

`strResponse` at line 47 contains the content of the login request itself (which is nothing), and `strResponse` at line 57 contains the content of the secured page.  This is the breakdown:

The following would happen if you were doing this in a web browser.

- You would type in the address of the secured page and hit Enter.
- Since you're not authenticated, the server would respond with a login form page.
- You would type in your username and password and click Submit.
- You would get your secure page.  The server would return a 302 redirect code with the address you originally requested, along with an authentication cookie, which your browser would store.  Your browser re-accesses this page, but now your browser sends the cookie as well, so instead of giving you a login form, you get the page you were trying to access.

Line 31 is the initial page access without authentication.
Lines 38-39 are displaying the login form, 
Lines 41-45 are the equivalent of typing your username and password into a form.
Line 47 is like hitting the Submit button.
Line 49 is showing what the server sent in response.  Notice in line 54 the comment is "Should be blank string".  When you submit the username and password, what you are most concerned about in the response is the HTTP status.  The comment in the line that prints out the status code says "Status code should be 302".  302 is the HTTP status which tells the browser to redirect.  The response headers would contain an address for your browser to redirect to.  The response headers also contain the authentication cookie.  It would be nice if that were printed out too, it would help with understanding how this all works.  The code is manually doing the redirect on line 57, but it is assuming that it will be redirected to the secured page it tried to access on line 31, rather than retrieving that address from the HTTP response headers.

The biggest change to `client` is that by line 57 `client` has the authentication cookie, similar to the browser operation.  DefaultHttpClient handles all that for you under the hood.

The authentication cookie comes from the server in the form of a Set-Cookie HTTP header.  This tells the `client` to store the cookie. Then, when making a request, the client sends a Cookie HTTP header, along with the cookie data.

The `client` initially receives the cookie on the response that contains the login form, which it stores.  When the `client` sends back the filled-in form, that cookie is also included in the request, and every request to the server thereafter.  So once you've authenticated, the server stores that information and associates it with the cookie.  Then, when subsequent requests come from the `client`, the server sees the cookie and remembers that you already authenticated. The `client` does all the same things a browser does to manage cookie data transfer with the server.

Comment: You know that your answer is almost a perfect copy of this : https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-form-based-authentication-using-HttpClient-through-j_security_check

Answer (score 0):

The "/j_security_check" is the endpoint used by Spring Framework to check user's credentials (you can find that information here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-filter, the default endpoint is "/j_spring_security_check").

The author knew that he/she had to use this URL because he/she had set the URL in Spring Framework's configuration (it is defined in the  element, to set the URL you have to modify the "login-processing-url" attribute).

Between lines 47 and 57 the client has been redirected to another URL and has retrieved that URL. The URL to which the client should be redirected is defined by the "default-target-url" attribute. Note that the Spring Framework may also redirect an user to the URL he/she requested before the login page has been displayed.

Comment: Thank you. But what physical changes exactly happen to the structure of `client` in between lines 47 and 57?  

Because if I created a new `DefaultHttpClient` (say `client 2`) object right before line 57 (with all the correct host, port, etc.), and called `httpResponse = client2.execute(securedResource);` using `client2`, the result entity of line 58 and the result string of line 59 would be different than if I would have just called all those methods with `client`.  

Something happens to `client` after line 47 is executed, that it makes is so you can get the secured resource in line 57.